# Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'm running into an error when trying to post a menu into my restaurant object using my create_menu_for_restaurant route.

```
Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks
```

```
def create_menu_for_restaurant(restaurant_id):
    """Creates and inserts new menu into restaurant database"""
    data = request.get_json()

    # input validation
    try:
         menu = Menu(**data).as_dict()
    except Exception as e:
         return make_response({"message": f"Incorrect data format {e}"}, 400)
    else:
        # update restaurant with new menu
        result = restaurants_collection.update_one({
             {"_id": restaurant_id},
             {"$push": {"menu": menu}}
            })
        # retrieve assigned id by db to new menu 
        menu_id = result.inserted_id

        return make_response({
            'message': 'new menu succesfully entered into database',
            'data': {"id": menu_id, **menu}}), 200
```

This is what my restaurant and menu classes look like

```
@dataclass()
class Restaurant(EnforcedTypeClass):
    name : str
    address : str
    phone_number : str
    email : str
    hours_of_operation : str
    menu : Union[Menu, None] = None
    
    def as_dict(self):
        return {
                'name' : self.name,
                'address' : self.address,
                'phone_number' : self.phone_number,
                'email' : self.email,
                'hours_of_operation' : self.hours_of_operation,
                'menu' : self.menu
        }

@dataclass()
class Menu(EnforcedTypeClass):
    restaurant_name : str
    address : str
    postnote : str
    sections : List[Section]
    
    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            'restaurant_name' : self.restaurant_name,
            'address': self.address,
            'postnote': self.postnote,
            'sections': self.sections
        }
```

I think the issue may lie somewhere in my type_validator.py

```
@dataclass()
class EnforcedTypeClass:
    def __post_init__(self):
        for (name, field_type) in self.__annotations__.items():
            if not isinstance(self.__dict__[name], field_type):
                current_type = type(self.__dict__[name])
                raise TypeError(f"The field `{name}` was assigned by `{current_type}` instead of `{field_type}`")
```

I've tried passing through into the validator as a dictionary and keep running into the same issue. Any guidance is appreciated.